# Using Protege owl ontology on Android

Tags: android, ontology, owl, protege

I have a practical seminar this semester, and I want to use ontology on Android application. 
I choose Protege owl ontology as a ontology API and this tool worked in normal Java project. But when I tried to import this jar files which for the owl ontology API in Android project.It will fail and I haven't found any solutions in the Internet.Can you help me?

Comment: on Android java is 1.5 check if the Protege is based on Java 1.5

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have a programmatic access to OWL ontologies using Java, you could use the [OWL-API](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/) directly, on the top of which Protege is built in the first place.

If your ontology follows a OWL 2EL profile you have also the possibility to use [Brain](http://loopasam.github.com/Brain/).

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this some time ago and it worked well.

Android Java is not standard Java, so you may need to port OWL-API (or whatever the library you choose, it can be Jena as well) java source code  to android platform. This may require some changes in source code as all the standard java classes are not available in android Java. This effort includes the library source jars if there are any.

Few ported libraries are available on android already. please refer this [link](http://code.google.com/p/androjena/)

Please note that performance wouldn't be good on device with the bigger ontologies.